# Has Xiaomi 12S Ultra computational raw?

Tags: raw, smartphone, computational-photography

Has Xiaomi 12S Ultra computational raw, like ProRaw from Apple or Expert Raw from Samsung?

Has any of Xiaomi phone's these stacked raw's or only regular single photo raw's ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can find the RAW mode in the pro settings of the camera app.